# editing shortcode for custom post type within a plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, taxonomy

My head is spinning on this code. I'm trying to add the ability to an existing plugin's shortcode, to display only certain custom post types that contain a certain category name.

So far, I have this:

```
   public function shortcode_litters( $args ) {

    $output = '';
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'category' => ''
    ), $atts );
    $terms = get_terms('product_category');
            wp_reset_query();

    $query_args = array( 
        'post_type'         => 'litter',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'asc',
        'numberposts'       => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
                 array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $atts,
                ),
             ),

    );

    $litters = get_posts($query_args);

    if($litters) {

        $columns = empty($args["columns"]) ? 2 : $args["columns"];

        $output .= '<div class="breedr"><ul class="columns '.number_to_words($columns).'">';

        foreach ( $litters as $litter ) {
            $output .= $this->breedr_template( plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'public/partials/list-single-litter.php', $litter );
        }

        $output .= '</ul></div>';

    }
    else {
        $output .= "<span>No litter found.</span>";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

originally it was this:

```
  public function shortcode_litters( $args ) {

    $output = '';
    $query_from_date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3 months")));

    $query_args = array( 
        'post_type'         => 'litter',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'title',
        'order'             => 'asc',
        'numberposts'       => -1
    );

    if(!empty($args['show']) && in_array($args['show'], array('current', 'past'))) {
        if ($args['show'] == "current") { 
            $meta_query = array(
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'       => '_litter_mating',
                        'value'     => $query_from_date,
                        'compare'   => '>=',
                        'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
                    )
                )
            );
        }
        if ($args['show'] == "past") {
            $meta_query = array(
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'       => '_litter_mating',
                        'value'     => $query_from_date,
                        'compare'   => '<',
                        'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }
    else {
        $meta_query = array('meta_query' => '');
    }

    $litters = get_posts($query_args + $meta_query);

    if($litters) {

        $columns = empty($args["columns"]) ? 2 : $args["columns"];

        $output .= '<div class="breedr"><ul class="columns '.number_to_words($columns).'">';

        foreach ( $litters as $litter ) {
            $output .= $this->breedr_template( plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'public/partials/list-single-litter.php', $litter );
        }

        $output .= '</ul></div>';

    }
    else {
        $output .= "<span>No litter found.</span>";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Essentially, I'm changing the shortcode from `[litters show=""]` to `[litters category=""]` - as I want it to display via category name (not number) in the shortcode. Originally, it has `show=""` (current or past) and it determines which one it is based on the date. I want to manually be able to determine if it is current or past by selecting a category name via the shortcode.

I've been trying to figure this out all day, and I'm brain dead at this point. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `$atts` is always `$atts = [ 'category' => '' ]`, you cannot use `'terms' => $atts,` in query parameters `$query_args`.

```
[litters category="first_slug,second_slug"]
```

You can assign to `'terms'` in [`'tax_query'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) parameter a string (single category) or an array (multiple category). `$args['category']` is passed to the shortcode function **as string**, so you need to check if it's one category and no action is required, or a list of slugs separated by commas and they must be converted to an array.

```
public function shortcode_litters( $args ) {

    $output = '';
    //
    // filter shortcode attributes
    $args = shortcode_atts( 
        array( 'category' => '', 'columns' => '' ), 
        $args 
    );
    if ( strpos( $args['category'], ',' ) !== false ) {
        $terms = explode( ',', $args['category'] );
    } else {
        $terms = $args['category'];
    }

    $query_args = array( 
        'post_type'         => 'litter',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'asc',
        'numberposts'       => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $terms,
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Comment: This worked like magic, THANK YOU!

Comment: Actually, all works until I add two categories : [litters category="first_slug,second_slug"] This breaks it, and I get these errors:
Warning: explode() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /data/27/5/118/151/5444477/user/6515207/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/breedr/public/class-breedr-public.php on line 475

Warning: explode() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /data/27/5/118/151/5444477/user/6515207/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/breedr/public/class-breedr-public.php on line 475
No litter found.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again, you're amazing :)